# SAPUI5 Planning Calendar need appointments in one line

Tags: sapui5, width, appointment

I'm trying to use the PlanningCalender from SAPUI5. However, I have a problem when I switch to the week view. Here appointments that are close together are written in a new line. But I don't want this behavior. All appointments should be written one after the other, even if I can then no longer read the content of the appointments.
It seems like there is a minimum width for appointments. But I can't find a way to change this appointment width.
Does anyone have an idea how I can get the appointments one after the other?

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/d1iswsOLseomX3R9?preview)

```
       sap.ui.define([
  'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
  'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
  'sap/m/Dialog',
  'sap/m/Button'
  ],
    function(Controller, JSONModel,Dialog, Button) {
    "use strict";
 
    var PageController = Controller.extend("sample1.View1", {
 
        onInit: function () {
            // create model
            var oModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.setData({
                startDate: new Date("2015", "11", "15", "8", "0"),
                people: [
                                {
                                    pic: "sap-icon://employee",
                                    name: "John Doe",
                                    role: "team member",
                                    appointments: [
                                                   {
                                                     start: new Date("2015", "11", "15", "08", "30"),
                                                     end: new Date("2015", "11", "15", "10", "30"),
                                                     title: "Meeting",
                                                     type: "Type02",
                                                     tentative: false
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     start: new Date("2015", "11", "15", "10", "30"),
                                                     end: new Date("2015", "11", "15", "12", "0"),
                                                     title: "Team meeting",
                                                     info: "room 1",
                                                     type: "Type01",
                                                     pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                                                     tentative: false
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     start: new Date("2015", "11", "15", "12", "00"),
                                                     end: new Date("2015", "11", "15", "13", "30"),
                                                     title: "Lunch",
                                                     type: "Type03",
                                                     tentative: true
                                                   }
                                                   ]
                                }
                ]
            });
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
 
        },
 
        handleAppointmentSelect: function (oEvent) {
            var oAppointment = oEvent.getParameter("appointment");
            if (oAppointment) {
                alert("Appointment selected: " + oAppointment.getTitle());
            }else {
                var aAppointments = oEvent.getParameter("appointments");
                var sValue = aAppointments.length + " Appointments selected";
                alert(sValue);
            }
        },
        handleIntervalSelect:function(oEvent){
          
          var dialogData = {
            newEntry: {
            start: oEvent.getParameter("startDate"),
                end: oEvent.getParameter("endDate"),
                title: "",
                info: "",
                type: "Type01",
                pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                tentative: false
            },
            people: this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/people").map(function(p,i){ return { name: p.name, index: i, selected: true }; }) //A List of all people. All selected by default.
                };
            var dialogModel = new JSONModel(dialogData);
            var that = this;
            var planningDialog = new Dialog({
              title:"Add Appointment",
              content: sap.ui.xmlview({viewName:"sample1.AppointmentDialog"}).setModel(dialogModel),
              leftButton: new Button({
                text: "Cancel", 
                press: function(){ 
                  planningDialog.close(); 
                  planningDialog.destroy();
                }}),
              rightButton: new Button({
                text: "Save", 
                type: "Accept",
                press: function(){ 
                  planningDialog.close(); 
                  that.addAppointment(dialogData);
                }}),
              
            });
            planningDialog.open();
            
        },
        addAppointment:function(data){
          var model = this.getView().getModel();
          var peopleList = model.getProperty("/people");
          data.people
            .filter(function(p){return p.selected;})
            .forEach(function(p){ 
              peopleList[p.index].appointments.push(data.newEntry);
            });
            model.setProperty("/people",peopleList); //Updates Bindings
        }
 
    });
 
    return PageController;
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setBuiltInViews
Sets a new value for property builtInViews.

Defines the list of predefined views as an array. The views should be specified by their keys.

The default predefined views and their keys are available at sap.m.PlanningCalendarBuiltInView.

Note: If set, all specified views will be displayed along with any custom views (if available). If not set and no custom views are available, all default views will be displayed. If not set and there are any custom views available, only the custom views will be displayed.

When called with a value of null or undefined, the default value of the property will be restored.

Default value is [].

What you are looking for is somehow tweak -- sap.m.PlanningCalendarBuiltInView.Week.

Haven't worked on it, will look for the solution! All the best!